# No output, even with `py.test -s`

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest, xdist, python-hunter

I would like to use `py.test` combined with [hunter](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-hunter):

```
PYTHONHUNTER="module_startswith='foo'" py.test -s -k test_bar
```

Unfortunately the output (trace) of hunter is not visible.

Version:

```
foo_cok_d@aptguettler:~$ py.test --version

This is pytest version 3.4.2, imported from /home/foo_cok_d/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest.pyc
setuptools registered plugins:
  pytest-xdist-1.22.2 at /home/foo_cok_d/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xdist/looponfail.py
  pytest-xdist-1.22.2 at /home/foo_cok_d/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xdist/plugin.py
  pytest-forked-0.2 at /home/foo_cok_d/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_forked/__init__.pyc
```

In a simpler (smaller) virtualenv it works (same pytest version, but no plugins).

What could be the reason?

How to debug this?

Comment: Docs seem to state you need to do `PYTHONHUNTER="Q(module_startswith='foo')"`. Did you try that? Also, is that the complete trace?

Comment: @dan-klasson `PYTHONHUNTER="module_startswith='foo'" ` is a valid syntax. It works for command line scripts. But not for pytest. What do you mean with "is that the complete trace?" ?

Comment: Stacktrace I mean. This looks very specific to the library. I'd post it as a issue on their github

Comment: @dan-klasson there is no stacktrace. Just a verbose `--version` output.

Comment: works for me, cant reproduce.

Comment: @georgexsh thank you very much for checking this. Maybe a pytest plugin is fooling me here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a work-around.

If I these two lines, then the `-s` option (shortcut for --capture=no) for `py.test` works.

```
    def test_when_the_moon_is_in_the_seventh_house(self):
+        import hunter
+        hunter.trace(module_startswith='modlink')
        ...
```

And I will see the race, and I am happy.

A solution without modifying the source code would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use respective pytest options for debugging:

   `pytest -v --tb=long`
2. Run program in debug mode with breakpoints in your IDE.

Example: [How to debug in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-breakpoints.html).